# Probability confusion (conditional vs. absolute)

Tags: probability

I have a probability question that I can't figure out by myself. Here is the problem statement:

*A company purchases apples from a vendor. Let $B_1$, $B_2$ and $B_3$ denote the probability of the first, second and third batch of purchased apples being rotten. The probability of any given batch being rotten is $0.05$. The probability of the current batch being rotten, given that the previous batch was rotten, is $0.2$. The probability of current batch being rotten, given that the last 2 batches were rotten, is $0.1$.*

The company certainly was buying apples before the first batch, so it is possible that upon buying the first batch, the "zeroth" batch was either rotten or not rotten. I am confused as to how to calculate the following probabilities:

1) $P(B_1)$

2) $P(B_2)$

3) $P(B_3 | B_2)$

Directly from the problem statement, it seems as though the answers should be:

1) $P(B_1)=0.05$

2) $P(B_2)=0.05$

3) $P(B_3 | B_2)=0.2$

But this somehow doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't for example $P(B_3 | B_2)$ be different from $0.2$ because of the possibility of $B_1$ being rotten, which would decrease the probability of $P(B_3)$ being rotten, for example?

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: why do you think that possibility of B1 being rotten would decrease the probability of P(B3)being rotten? Is it becoz vendor will take care in buying future batches?

Comment: This is one of the odd things about probability. Even though, physically, you know the first batch was either rotten or not, you have no information about it. Thus you have to account for both possibilities. You can think of it as adding an additional condition: that the first batch is either rotten or not. Of course that adds nothing to the calculation. Try it as an exercise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answers are correct. You don't know whether $B_1$ is rotten, so you need the conditional probability conditional only upon $B_2$ being rotten. The fact that $B_1$ could be rotten doesn't matter, because it also could be OK, and the unconditional probability accounts for both possibilities. You seem to be thinking in terms of $B_1$ only influencing the probability for $B_3$ in one direction; in fact you seem to almost be confusing the unconditional probability with the conditional probability under the condition of $B_1$ not being rotten. The three relevant probabilities are:

\begin{align}
P(B_3\mid B_2)&=0.2\;,\\
P(B_3\mid B_2\cap B_1)&=0.1\;,\\
P(B_3\mid B_2\cap \overline{B_1})&=p\;.
\end{align}

By the law of total probability,

\begin{align}
0.2&=P(B_3\mid B_2)\\
&=P(B_3\mid B_2\cap B_1)P(B_1\mid B_2)+P(B_3\mid B_2\cap \overline{B_1})P(\overline{B_1}\mid B_2)\\
&=0.1\cdot0.2+pP(\overline{B_1}\mid B_2)\\
&=0.1\cdot0.2+p\left(1-P(B_1\mid B_2)\right)\\
&=0.1\cdot0.2+p\left(1-\frac{P(B_1)}{P(B_2)}P(B_2\mid B_1)\right)\\
&=0.1\cdot0.2+p\left(1-P(B_2\mid B_1)\right)\\
&=0.1\cdot0.2+0.8p\;,\\
\end{align}

So $P(B_3\mid B_2\cap \overline{B_1})=p=0.225$. The probability for $B_3$ to be rotten is slightly increased if $B_1$ is OK, and slightly decreased if $B_1$ is rotten, and if you don't know anything about $B_1$, you don't need to worry about that and just use the unconditional probability, which contains both cases.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for this explanation! It cleared everything up. The last sentence, "The probability for $B_3$ to be rotten is slighly increased if $B_1$ is OK, and slightly decreased if $B_1$ is rotten, and if you don't know anything about $B_1$, you don't need to worry about that and just use the unconditional probability, which contains both cases" is what made it click.